# Regular expression with alpha, hyphens, underscore and dots characters

Tags: regex

I've wrote a regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\-\_\. ]{2,60}$/
```

It does work fine-ish however it allows --- or ___ or ... or even -_. to be entered as an input (without 2 alpha at least) and I don't want that. For instance I can have -aa, a-a, aa--- (similarly for the other characters).

The requirement is that there should be at least 2 alpha in the string, and the hyphens and the other 2 non-alpha symbols mentioned can be anywhere inside the string.

Comment: Could you please clarify the rules? At least 2 alpha anywhere in the string? Or just disallow a string that has no letters?

Comment: To be clear - do you want a minimum of two alphabetical characters? And then there may be any combination of hyphens, underscores, periods and spaces interspersed?

Comment: Sorry, yes at least 2 alpha in the string. That is a requirement.

Comment: The hyphens and the other 2 characters mentioned can be anywhere. Ideally a max of ten (for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
/^(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){2})[-_. a-zA-Z]{2,60}$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6wqSGV/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){2})` - at least 2 alpha chars in the string (that is, there must be exactly 2 consecutive occurrences of:

  - `[^a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more chars other than ASCII letters
  - `[a-zA-Z]`  - an ASCII letter)
- `[-_. a-zA-Z]{2,60}` - 2 to 60 occurrences of allowed chars
- `$` - end of string

Note you do not need to escape `-` if it is at the start/end of the character class. `_` is a word char, no need escaping it anywhere. The `.` does not need escaping inside a character class.

To tell the regex engine to limit `.`, `_` and `-` chars to max 10 in the string, add `(?!(?:[^._-]*[._-]){11})` negative lookahead after `^` anchor:

```
/^(?!(?:[^._-]*[._-]){11})(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){2})[-_. a-zA-Z]{2,60}$/
```

Comment: Can I add a limit of ten hyphens or dots or undescores to it?

Comment: Yes, add `(?!(?:[^._-]*[._-]){11})` after `^`.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiże: Done that mate